# Training data label not reliable

Tags: machine-learning, training-data

I am doing a project where I have some training data but some of its labels are not very reliable. The labels are of two categories-male and female. The problem is that some people might have filled in the wrong gender when registering their accounts for whatever reason.

Is there any general way to overcome this problem- mislabelled data?

Comment: Most machine learning techniques tend to handle *noise* (as this phenomena is called) quite well, given there is enough data to conclude it was a mistake. Unless you know which data, there is not really much you can do about this.

Comment: There is not much you can do about this.  One check you _could_ perform would be to see how many total men and women you have and to compare this against a known number.

Comment: Perhaps this question should be moved to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There are numerous possibilities (cross validation, nearest neighbour, ...) to identify questionable labels for a manual review to avoid complete reviews. But as I understand you have no possibility to review questionable labels. You have to accept that 'noise' and hope that the data is indeed randomly mislabled.

Comment: @stefan How do you use cross validation to test if there are mis-labelled data? Since the error could originate from the prediction of classifier or the mislabelled data, what should I do about this?

Comment: @CommuSoft The noise ratio in the training data is somehow big. I would say 3/10 of the gender could be wrong. What classifier do you recommend could handle such large noise? Thanks.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sadly I do not know how many men or women in total there are.

Comment: @zhangrui: By cross validation you find data samples where the classification result contradicts the manual labeling. If you have the possibility to manually review the real class you can iteratively improve your labeling without having to redo the labeling for the complete data set. If your initial classifier is very bad because of very bad initial labeling you will need many iterations until you end up with a classifier where all contradictions are classifier errors. there still may be mislabeld samples in your data set but the classifier may be sufficient while not guaranteed to be optimal.

Comment: @stefan I understand what you said, but my problem is that I do not know the real class. All I know is some users filled in the wrong gender. I don't know who and I don't know how many. So even if I manually check out the data, I still do not know whether or not it is real or not.

Comment: @zhangrui. as I said in my first comment you have to accept that 'noise' and hope that the data is indeed randomly mislabled.There is no way to generate Information out of nowhere. Without valid ground truth you have no guarantee about your classifier performance. If there is a systematical mislabeling (correlating to your features) you have absolutely no possibility to find out. your classifier will perfectly predict a persons answer but not the whether it is true. In case of random mislabeling it will tell the true sex as random noise is ignored (while possibly causing some performance drop)